# Python script installed via setup.py dependency conflict

Tags: python, setup.py

I'm not usually a python user, but have to install this application written in python >3.6, so please be more specific in the details.

I install a python application via setup.py like this

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

At the end of installation it prints something like this:

```
...
Processing dependencies for gasprice==1.1.5
Searching for websockets<8.0.0,>=7.0.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/websockets/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/71/8bfa882b9c502c36e5c9ef6732969533670d2b039cbf95a82ced8f762b80/websockets-7.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=79691794288bc51e2a3b8de2bc0272ca8355d0b8503077ea57c0716e840ebaef
Best match: websockets 7.0
Processing websockets-7.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing websockets-7.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl to /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Adding websockets 7.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/websockets-7.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg
error: websockets 7.0 is installed but websockets<7.0,>=6.0 is required by {'sanic'}
```

So it seems to first install websockets 7.0 because it is required by one of the dependencies, but then can't install another dependency because it requires websockets <7.0.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Did you try uninstalling websockets 7.0 and installing a version between 6.0 and 7.0 ? That way it won't install the lastest version of websockets and you won't have an error

Comment: Yes, I did `sudo pip3 uninstall websockets` and then `sudo pip3 install websockets==6.0` but I still get the same error

Comment: Have you tried installing websockets 6.0 then installing sanic then retrying ?

Comment: Yes, I still get the same error

Comment: What are all of the dependencies listed in `setup.py`?

Comment: 'sanic',
        'pandas',
        'web3>=4.0.0b4',
        'click',
        'retry',